# XSLT european number Formatting

Tags: xslt, format

I want to transform this number 4165087318 into this european format 41.650.873,18
I've tried this

ACTUAL is where the value comes from

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(ACTUAL, ".###.###,##")' />
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(ACTUAL, "###,###.00")' />
```

The second one I tried , actually gave me something

41,650,873.18

but I need the commas and the dots to be like in the example I mentioned above and I can't seem to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To realize a european value notation you have to define your own `decimal-format` at the top level of the stylesheet

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>
```

and then use it explicitly in `format-number`:

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(ACTUAL, "###.###,00", "european")' />
```

Output is:

```
4.165.087.318,00
```

Comment: Only picked this up today!
It worked perfectly thanks!